# Clear Anypoint Studio Memory Usage?

Tags: memory-leaks, mule, anypoint-studio

I am developing in Anypoint Studio 6.2 and am finding as I run my code the memory usage creeps up and up. Starting at approx. 800mb, after half an hour or so Anypoint is using around 9gb (I have 16gb of RAM).

The doesnt go down when I stop running and usually Anypoint hangs when I try and close it.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any ways to combat it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start Anypoint studio in clean mode. for this what you need to do is locate anypointstudio.ini in your install directory.

edit the file and place

```
-clean
```

as the first line in the file.

you might also consider checking and updating the

memory size params.

a complete example for your reference below:

```
-clean
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-vmargs
-Xms584m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=784m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/AnypointStudio/workspace
```

Comment: I tried this but it hasn't stopped the problem. Over time, the amount of memory Anypoint uses creeps up and up, slowing down until I have to manually close it through Task Manager.

Comment: thats how anypoint studio is. the other option (which i am following) is to comment out the flows that are irrelevant for your current development which will avoid validating the whole project everytime you change anything in one flow. it really saves me lot of time.